# Getting non-exponent version of float in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

Elixir is outputting: 3.5e-4

I want to display: 0.00035

Is there a way to constrain Elixir to output the non-exponent version of the float?

Comment: What do you mean by "output"? Are you thinking about displaying a string, like "0.00035"? You could try wrapping the float in `Decimal`, eg: `Decimal.new(0.00035) # => #Decimal<0.00035>` and this `to_string`, so: `Decimal.new(0.00035) |> to_string # => "0.00035"`

Comment: Maybe `:erlang.float_to_binary(3.5e-4, [:compact, decimals: 20])` (the default is `[scientific: 20]`.

Comment: Anyway to do this without knowing the decimal precision, (in the edge case beyond 20)?

Comment: I can suggest _performing_ calculations using [`Decimal`](https://hexdocs.pm/decimal/readme.html).

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule if you want precise control of output, you need to use the underlying erlang library `io:format`.

[Erlang io format](http://erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#format-1)

It's somewhat unique, although it more or less works like printf or sprintf in other languages. If you are more familiar with those functions there is an Elixir library that translates for you.

https://github.com/parroty/exprintf

The Float.to_string function is what is used for printing floats, as far as I can tell there is no way to override the format it uses.

Comment: `Float.to_string` is deprecated in favour of  `:erlang.float_to_binary`. As @Dogbert pointed out in his comment, you can override the format with the [decimals: xx] option. This works fine up to 20. However, it you give it a number > 20, the decimal portion shows incorrect rounding. Elixir floats are 64bit double precision. I believe the maximum decimal digits is 16, so I would suspect that the value of 20 would be fine.

Comment: That's not what the current master says. https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/float.ex#L433 Looks like Float.to_string/2 is deprecated.

Comment: Thats what I said ... "Float.to_string is deprecated in favour of :erlang.float_to_binary". The  `decimals` option can be given to `:erlang.float_to_binary`

Comment: I've used `exprintf` in the past, but not for a long time now. Has a much nicer syntax than erlang's format stuff IMHO.